# Can't all or most cases of `each` be replaced with `map`?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, each

The difference between `Enumerable#each` and `Enumerable#map` is whether it returns the receiver or the mapped result. Getting back to the receiver is trivial and you usually do not need to continue a method chain after `each` like `each{...}.another_method` (I probably have not seen such case. Even if you want to get back to the receiver, you can do that with `tap`). So I think all or most cases where `Enumerable#each` is used can be replaced by `Enumerable#map`. Am I wrong? If I am right, what is the purpose of `each`? Is `map` slower than `each`?

**Edit**:
I know that there is a common practice to use `each` when you are not interested in the return value. I am not interested in whether such practice exists, but am interested in whether such practice makes sense other than from the point of view of convention.

Comment: You do understand that `each` is a fundamental part of Enumerable whereas `map` is not, right? ["The class must provide a method `each`, which yields successive members of the collection."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

Comment: @muistooshort I wan't aware of that. I will think about it. Thanks.

Comment: Try implementing `map` in terms of `each` and then `each` in terms of `map`, that might give you a bit of insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The choice between `map` or `each` should be decided by the desired end result: a new array or no new array. The result of `map`  can be huge and/or silly:

```
p ("aaaa".."zzzz").map{|word| puts word} #huge and useless array of nil's
```

Comment: If it is slow, I understand I should not use it, but why is it silly? I don't understand that at all. Ruby inherited from Lisp the idea that every evaluation returns a value.

Comment: The result of this `map` is an array with 456976 nil's (`puts` returns a nil). It is discarded after being created. Using `each` would not have created it at all, saving memory. (Code slightly adjusted)

Comment: That was what I am asking. Whether it makes difference performance-wise.

Comment: It's also semantics. Another person reading your code will likely wonder *why* you decided to use `map`, and what your goal in using it was, when really there wasn't any.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `map` and `each` is more important than whether one returns a new array and the other doesn't.  The important difference is in how they communicate your intent.

When you use `each`, your code says "I'm doing something for each element."  When you use `map`, your code says "I'm creating a new array by transforming each element."

So while you could use `map` in place of `each`, performance notwithstanding, the code would now be lying about its intent to anyone reading it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what you said. `Enumerable#each` simply returns the original object it was called on while `Enumerable#map` sets the current element being iterated over to the return value of the block, and then returns a new object with those changes.

Since `Enumerable#each` simply returns the original object itself, it can be very well preferred over the `map` when it comes to cases where you need to simply iterate or traverse over elements.

In fact, `Enumerable#each` is a simple and universal way of doing a traditional iterating for loop, and each is much preferred over for loops in Ruby.

Comment: I am honestly not interested in how other people prefer one method over the other. I am interested in whether it makes sense to have a distinguished use of `each`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the significant difference between `map` and `each` when you're composing these enumaratiors.

For example you need to get new array with indixes in it:

```
array.each.with_index.map { |index, element| [index, element] }
```

Or for example you just need to apply some method to all elements in array and print result without changing the original array:

```
m = 2.method(:+)

[1,2,3].each { |a| puts m.call(a) } #=> prints 3, 4, 5
```

And there's a plenty another examples where the difference between `each` and `map` is important key in the writing code in functional style.